# Did I lose a lot of ADA after updating Cardano node?? Alonzo hardfork

Tags: wallet, cardano-node

So, the context is I have cardano-wallet and node deployed via docker-compose. I do have mnemonic codes, wallet passphrase, id/label, everything. For alonzo hardfork, I had to upgrade my node which I did. Firstly, since its docker-compose I had to change versions, removed current running containers and build new ones. I did, but node never started, kept restarting, upon investigation logs it was some linux user/permission issue. It made sense that it wasn't going to just work with previous volumes. I went ahead and purged volumes, tried again and good that this time it worked and started syncing.

Using RPC API I restored my wallets, there are about 65k addresses in 1 wallet and 4-5 thousand addresses in other 2 wallets. After restoring, I matched addresses and all of them are a 100% match which validates that private key has been restored correctly but even after complete sync all addresses are marked as "unused" and wallet has "0" balance. :((((

Any help will be appreciated, I have a lot of money in ADA and assets on the line here.

Comment: Hey @FieldMarshal, let us know what you figured out (as it's been 21 days). It will help others in the future who may have similar problems.

Answer (score 2):

Check your node sync status with `cardano-cli query tip`. Likely your wallet is synced, but your node is not caught up yet.